# With Tensorflow, how to reduce sparse volumetric tensors to target voxels for improved network training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am creating an auto-encoder neural network to perform semantic segmentation of 3D volumetric data. The data is sparse (only about 1% of the voxels represent actual structure being classified while the remaining 99% is void/nothing/empty). Although each 3D volumetric image is 64x64x64 voxels, each has a unique structured size and shape so I cannot uniformly flatten all input to a specific indices.

The goal is the have the neural network classify each voxel that represents the actual structure (that 1%). Currently the back propagation is reducing loss by comparing the full volumetric data output to the full labeled output. This produces an artificially high accuracy of 99% since predicting nothing/void is easy to learn. My goal is to have the loss function not use the full volumetic data but rather only the 1% of the volumetric data that contains structure data.

My question is a little bit on the design end, but how would one reduce the output of the neural network and the labels to include only the structured voxels given the fact that each image will be unique?

More details:

1. Input/Output/Labels of the network are all (3D volumetric data): 64x64x64 voxels
2. Input data is always zero in the empty voxels (99%) and non-zero in the structure voxels (1%).
3. Label data is always zero in the empty voxels and a class label 1/2/3/4 in the structure voxels.

Here is my current incomplete code along with psuedocode of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x) # Dimentions: (? x 64 x 64 x 64)
zero_tensor = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
y_structured_data = tf.not_equal(y, zero_tensor)
# Use y_structured_data on prediction-Tensor to find structure voxels
# reduce both Tensors to eliminate empty space. (Possibly using y_structured_data)
# Feed those reduced Tensors to the loss function.
loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=reduced_prediction, labels=reduced_y)
```

I have tried using tf.boolean_mask(), and tf.where() to get the desired reduction but have yet to get that to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you weigh your loss function to give 0 weight to the empty voxels?

Comment: Yes that sounds like it would work. Would that require I write a custom loss function or can that be accomplished by zeroing out the empty voxels in both the logits and labels and then sending them to the current loss function.

Comment: Many loss functions have an additional `weights` input argument. You can feed in a tensor with a size that matches the label size. See for example https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy

Comment: Thank you @mikkola. I created a boolean mask from the nonzero voxels and used it as the `weights` parameter for my loss function. This forced the loss to be calculated from the non-void voxels only.